# How to handle masks (enums) in Swift 2.0?

Tags: swift, enums, eventkit, swift2

For example in EventKit there is a property on `EKCalendar` called `supportedEventAvailabilities` which is of type `EKCalendarEventAvailabilityMask`. It is a mask of all the supported event availabilities. I know you could theoretically set them like this (if this property was writable):

```
calendar.supportedEventAvailabilities = [.Busy, .Free]
```

But how do you read those values again? I ended up with code like this:

```
let availabilities = calendar.supportedEventAvailabilities
if (availabilities.rawValue & EKCalendarEventAvailabilityMask.Busy.rawValue) == EKCalendarEventAvailabilityMask.Busy.rawValue {
    // 'Busy' is in there!
}
if (availabilities.rawValue & EKCalendarEventAvailabilityMask.Free.rawValue) == EKCalendarEventAvailabilityMask.Free.rawValue {
    // 'Free' is in there!
}
```

But this does not feel right. Does anyone know how to do this properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EKCalendarEventAvailabilityMask` conforms to the new `OptionSetType`
protocol  which inherits from `SetAlgebraType` and offers a set-like interface. You can check for membership with

```
let availabilities = calendar.supportedEventAvailabilities
if availabilities.contains(.Busy) {
    // 'Busy' is in there!
}
```

or

```
if availabilities.isSupersetOf([.Busy, .Free]) {
    // Both .Busy and .Free are available ...
}
```

or

```
if availabilities.intersect([.Busy, .Free]) != [] {
    // At least one of .Busy and .Free is available ...
}
```

For more information, see [`protocol SetAlgebraType`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SetAlgebraType_Protocol/index.html)
in the "Swift Standard Library Reference".

Comment: Very cool. That's much cleaner than doing bitwise operations on the enum's raw values. Another trick I didn't know about. Was that added in Swift 1.2?